# How to add/update/delete n-n tables?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've this tables on my SQL Server Database:

[image]

On my `ASP.NET MVC` app I manage the `Clinics` for each `Medical`. So let say `Medical ID 1` can have N associated Clinics, such as `Clinic ID 5, 8, 10`.

Here's my attempt in the `Controller's Action`:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    Medicals medical = mapper.Map<MedicalViewModel, Medicals>(medicalViewModel);

    // medical
    ctx.Entry(medical).State = medical.ID == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;

    ctx.SaveChanges();

    // relationships medical/clinics
    foreach (var clinic in medicalViewModel.ClinicsList)
    {
        Clinics clinics = new Clinics() { ID = clinic.ID };

        // delete
        if (!clinic.IsChecked)
        {
            medical.Clinics.Remove(clinics);
        }
        // add/update
        else
        {
            medical.Clinics.Add(clinics);
        }
    }

    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

But its not able to either delete or add/update.

Where am I wrong? I don't have the table `ClinicsMedicals` generated by `Entity Framework`, so I guess I need to access by `Medicals`.

Comment: In nornam sql , you would have to delete the link between then before you can link them, that means deleting ClinicsMedicals before you can delete either clinic or medicals

Comment: Its what I'm trying to do, but using code and entity relationship directly :)

Comment: haven't used EF in a long time, doesnt it create a ClinicsMedical class for you? maybe you can remove that class first before you remove the relationship.

Comment: He no, there isn't :) I don't need to remove Medicals or Clinics, but its relationship (such as the clinics associated at the Medical, or add new ones).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I think you need to do:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    Medicals medicalEntity;
    if(medicalViewModel.ID == 0)
    {
        medicalEntity = ctx.Set<Medicals>().Add(new Medicals());
    }
    else
    {
        // retrieve existing entity
        medicalEntity = ctx.Set<Medicals>().Find(medicalViewModel.ID);

        if(medicalEntity == null)
            // log and throw exception may be?
    }

    // apply new changes to existing entity
    medicalEntity = mapper.Map<MedicalViewModel, Medicals>(medicalViewModel, medicalEntity);

    // relationships medical/clinics
    foreach (var clinicViewModel in medicalViewModel.ClinicsList)
    {
        var clinicEntity = medicalEntity.Clinics.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == clinicViewModel.ID);

        // delete
        if (!clinicViewModel.IsChecked)
        {
            medicalEntity.Clinics.Remove(clinicEntity);
        }
        else
        {
            if(clinicEntity == null) // add
            {
                medicalEntity.Clinics.Add(ctx.Set<Clinics>().Find(clinicViewModel.ID));
            }
            else
            {
                // update
            }
        }
    }

    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: It seems to works perfectly! Note: typo `FirstOfDefault`, its "or" default ;)